# MySQL Workbench 5.2 doesn't start on Windows 7 Ultimate 64-Bit

Tags: windows-7, installation, 64-bit, mysql-workbench

I just installed MySQL Workbench 5.2 and everything went well. But I can't manage to start it. It shows no error message, and no splash screen.

I've tried to troubleshoot compatibility, but with no success.

Any thoughts?

Comment: From I experience, I have found this to be a buggy pieced of software. however, have you any previous versions of Workbench installed?

Comment: No, its a fresh install of windows.

Comment: get Visual C++ 2010 redistributable x32 & NET Framework 4 Client Profile x64

Comment: +1 for x32 version of C++ 2010, even if you are running a x64 PC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw in the Event Viewer that this application causes a fault in KERNELBASE.dll (Id = 1000).

Install an older version (`mysql-workbench-oss-5.0.30-win32.msi`), and this is working.

I have Win 7 Home Premium.

Answer (score 4):

Installing the 32 bits version of Visual C++ redistributables (vcredist_x86.exe), even if you use Windows 7 Pro x64, should fix the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Uninstall .NET Framework 4 Client Profile and Visual C++ redistributables (I had a bunch) from your computer (using Programs and Features) and re-install the most recent .NET Framework 4 Client Profile and Visual C++ 2010 redistributable.

I had the same problem using Windows 7 64-bit and I fixed it this way.

Answer (score 1):

Fresh install of WB 5.2.35 CE and Visual C++ 2010 redistributable x86, no other changes, hacks or installs (or reinstalls) did the trick for me.